# PHP function from included file

Tags: php, function, scope, include

I think I read that one before, but can't find any infos on that issue.

I get an *Error: Call to undefined function* when I try to echo my function, from within an included file.

Setup:
**bootstrap.php** <-- I run this script

```
include 'header.php';
echo 'content comes here';
```

**header.php**

```
include 'functions.php';
echo test();
```

**functions.php**

```
function test() {
  return 'test';
}
// die('test');
```

When I uncomment the die()-function I can see it, so the functions.php is included.

But why is my test()-function not working? I believe I read something about the scope and included files. But I don't know exactly what is wrong.
It doesn't work either, if I include the functions.php in the bootstrap.php file directly. But if I do and put the test()-function inside the bootstrap.php it works.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. You're doing something (else) we don't know. You're probably including one file (or files) before the other.

Comment: *"When I uncomment the die()-function"* - That's probably because of the file order and it died before it could keep going. Make sure you don't have any rewrites happening neither.

Comment: I am doing this inside a CMS … but thought these are just plain PHP files (templates). That must be problem. Sorry!